# Silverlight interacting with peripheral device

Tags: java, silverlight-3.0

I am interested in creating a Silverlight application.  One of my requirements is to communicate with peripheral devices connected to the clients.  What is the best way to meet this requirement.  I would like to stay away from ActiveX and use possibly Java.  Writing a Silverlight application using Java to communicate with the client peripheral devices is the direction that I'm heading in.

I would like other developers feedback on their thoughts.  Is it difficult to communicate between Java and Silverlight?  I believe that Silverlight is limited to the browser sandbox for obvious reasons.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to communicate between Silverlight and Java.  The core application would be written in Silverlight but the communication between peripheral devices would be done in Java.  Using Java would bypass the browser sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing it using signed Java Applet or JavaFX?

Or doing a fully client side C#/Java solution?

I don't know Silverlight 3.0, but I doubt you can develop apps in Java language for it, more like in J#.

Could you give more details about your case/requirements/environment?

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from installing a client on an end users machine.  Silverlight offers features that are very easy to implement that would otherwise be relatively difficult using a non-RIA architecture.  One of the requirements is to integrate with a document scanner.  Another requirement is to integrate with bar code scanners.  Silverlight is restricted to the web browsers sandbox.  I was thinking that using a java type solution would solve my problem of communicating with peripheral devices and bridge the data to my Silverlight application.

Answer (score 0):

We've got a similar issue with our application: we want to access our users' microphones and web cams, but that feature got pulled from SL 3.0 for unknown reasons.  Our current approach is to use the HTML bridge/Javascript to access a simple Flash object, which we then overlay onto our Silverlight application.  (The basic approach is described [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-and-Flash-Interoperability-using-HTML-Bridge-and-ExternalInterface-API.aspx).)  You could conceivably do something similar, where you prompt the user to install, say, a small ActiveX control that provides similar access, and then talk to that AX control via JavaScript.  We're planning to move that direction, because the Flash microphone support sucks way too badly to be used in a real-world VOIP/conferencing scenario.

Answer (score 0):

we can use peripheral applets for the same and that will invoke a javascript method on landed jsp and we will have a control for the same